# Can't assign value refered to an static context of another module (undefined when trying to assign)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to do an Ionic app, and to make my code a bit more organized, I thought about separating certain things in other modules and importing them, the problem is that i'm getting 'undefined' when assigning a static variable from another module to the module where i'm trying to import it.

I tried to make the exported module to be static, so the module.ts (that i did mannually) looks like:

```
/*--------- Menu options---------*/
```

```js
    export class AppPages{

      public static pages = [

        {
          title: 'Inicio',
          url: '/home',
          icon: 'home',
          detailTag: 'basicInfo'
        },
        {
          title: 'Deportes',
          url: '/deportes',
          icon: 'american-football',
          detailTag: 'basicInfo'
        },
        {
          title: 'Citas',
          url: '/citas',
          icon: 'bowtie',
          detailTag: 'basicInfo'
        },
        {
          title: 'Bares',
          url: '/bares',
          icon: 'beer',
          detailTag: 'basicInfo'
        },
        {
          title: 'Comida',
          url: '/comida',
          icon: 'pizza',
          detailTag: 'basicInfo'
        },
        {
          title: 'Lugares turisticos',
          url: '/lugares-turisticos',
          icon: 'airplane',
          detailTag: 'basicInfo'
        },
        {
          title: 'Otros',
          url: '/',
          icon: 'disc',
          detailTag: 'basicInfo'
        },
        {
          title: 'Cambiar de cuenta',
          url: '/log-in',
          icon: 'browsers',
          detailTag: 'accountInfo'
        },
        {
          title: 'Configuración',
          url: '/account-config',
          icon: 'build',
          detailTag: 'accountInfo'
        },
        {
          title: 'Salir',
          url: '/',
          icon: 'exit',
          detailTag: 'accountInfo'
        }

      ];

      constructor(){}

    }
```

And for example in home.page.ts i try to import it:

```js
    import { AppPages } from '../global_modules/app_pages';
```

Now when i imported the module, i create a variable inside the class of `HomePage` like:

```js
    public appPages;
```

Full code of home.page.ts:

```js
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BackgroundDirective } from '../../assets/background.directive';/*This directive is needed in each page*/
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppPages } from '../../global_modules/app_pages';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})

export class HomePage {

  public gallery_main_route = '../assets/gallery/';
  public appPages;
  public galleryRadioButtons;
  public top_bar_avatar;
  public left_bar_menu_opener;
  public menuCtrl;

  public gallery_images = [

    {
        name: 'sample',
        extension: '.jpg',
        sample_gallery_text: '',
        alt: '',
        checked: 'true'
    },

    {
        name: 'sample2',
        extension: '.jpg',
        sample_gallery_text: '',
        alt: '',
        checked: 'false'
    },

    {
        name: 'sample3',
        extension: '.jpg',
        sample_gallery_text: '',
        alt: '',
        checked: 'false'
    },

    {
        name: 'sample4',
        extension: '.jpg',
        sample_gallery_text: '',
        alt: '',
        checked: 'false'
    },

    {
        name: 'sample5',
        extension: '.png',
        sample_gallery_text: '',
        alt: '',
        checked: 'false'
    }

  ];

  public sample_content = [

    {
        separator_title: 'Restaurantes',
        title: 'Restaurante x',
        src: '../assets/gallery/sample3.jpg',
        description: '¿Un lugar donde comer un platillo exquisito y ademas muy elegante?, suena tentador...',
      loved: 'heart-empty',
      favourite: 'star-outline'
    },
    {
        separator_title: 'Bares',
        title: 'Bar x',
        src: '../assets/gallery/sample4.jpg',
        description: '¿Quieres compartir alguna cerveza con alguien pero no tienes amigos?, con EXTIME, podrás hacerlo!',
      loved: 'heart-empty',
      favourite: 'star-outline'
    },
    {
        separator_title: 'Citas',
        title: 'Cita x',
        src: '../assets/gallery/sample2.jpg',
        description: '¿Eres sociable y deseas conocer y salir con aquellas personas?, EXTIME te da un medio para hacerlo!',
      loved: 'heart-empty',
      favourite: 'star-outline'
    },
    {
        separator_title: 'Lugares turisticos',
        title: 'Lugar turistico x',
        src: '../assets/gallery/sample.jpg',
        description: '¿Que mas placentero que ir de vacaciones a un hermoso lugar?, encuentra los mejores lugares en EXTIME!',
      loved: 'heart-empty',
      favourite: 'star-outline'
    },
    {
        separator_title: 'Lugares deportivos',
        title: 'Lugar deportivo x',
        src: '../assets/gallery/sample5.png',
        description: '¿Disfrutas tambien de hacer ejercicio?, ¡Ningun problema!, aquí en EXTIME, tambien encontraras lugares deportivos de interes personal en los cuales hacer deporte.',
      loved: 'heart-empty',
      favourite: 'star-outline'
    }

  ];

  constructor(public toastController: ToastController){

    this.appPages = AppPages.pages;

  }

  //This function allows you to add any event to an element, and you can attach a callback to that event and pass to it any needed parameters.
  addEvents(element, evType, attachCallback, ...callbackAttributes){

    element.addEventListener(evType, (ev) =>{

      attachCallback(ev, ...callbackAttributes);

    });

  }

  setup(){

    this.appPages = AppPages.pages;
    this.galleryRadioButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('circle_slider_component') as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;
    this.top_bar_avatar = document.getElementById('top_right_avatar');
    this.left_bar_menu_opener = document.getElementById("title_component").children[0];
    this.menuCtrl = document.querySelector('ion-menu-controller');

    console.log(this.appPages);

    //Adding menu custom display events.
    this.addEvents(this.top_bar_avatar, "click", this.hideShowMenu, "item-container","accountInfo");
    this.addEvents(this.left_bar_menu_opener, "click", this.hideShowMenu, "item-container", "basicInfo");

  }

  hideShowMenu(ev, elementClassReference,listReference){

    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName(elementClassReference);

    for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){

      if(!(this.appPages[i].detailTag === listReference)){

        elements[i].style.display = "none";

      }else{

        elements[i].style.display = "block";

      }

    }
    this.menuCtrl.open();

  }

  ionViewDidEnter(){

    this.setup();

  }

  async button_toast(message, index){

    switch(message){

      case 'loved':

        if(this.sample_content[index].loved == "heart-empty"){

          this.sample_content[index].loved = "heart";
          const toast = await this.toastController.create({
            message: '¡Haz indicado que te gusta esta pagina!',
            duration: 2000
          });
          return await toast.present();

        }else{

          this.sample_content[index].loved = "heart-empty";
          const toast = await this.toastController.create({
            message: '¡Ya no te gusta esta pagina!',
            duration: 2000
          });
          return await toast.present();

        }

        break;

      case 'favourite':

        if(this.sample_content[index].favourite == "star-outline"){

          this.sample_content[index].favourite = "star";
          const toast = await this.toastController.create({
            message: '¡Haz añadido esta pagina a favoritos!',
            duration: 2000
          });
          return await toast.present();

        }else{

          this.sample_content[index].favourite = "star-outline";
          const toast = await this.toastController.create({
            message: '¡Haz quitado esta pagina de favoritos!',
            duration: 2000
          });
          return await toast.present();

        }

        break;

    }

  }

}
```

When i console.log the value of variable appPages in setup after assignement , i get the correct info (is not undefined), but when other function tries to get the content of that variable, Throws me this error:

> core.js:15724 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'appPages' of undefined
>       at push../src/app/home/home.page.ts.HomePage.hideShowMenu (home.page.ts:144)
>       at HTMLElement. (home.page.ts:118)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
>       at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:498)
>       at invokeTask (zone.js:1744)
>       at HTMLElement.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1770)

¿Why is 'not assigned'?, (take in account that when i console.log the content of the variable appPages, i'm getting the correct info, not undefined).

Comment: can you also share example of another function attempting to use appPages value? where in your code such attempt is made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved!, the problem was i attempt to use the value of the JSON after the page was loaded (and i load some info with this JSON to the HTML), that is!, so i changed the assignment to this:

```
//some stuff...

public appPages;

ionViewWillEnter(){

  this.setup();

}

ionViewDidEnter(){

   /*And here after the page was loaded, i use the functions that requires
    *that value.*/
   this.hideShowMenu();

}

setup(){

  this.appPages = AppPages.pages;

}
```

But i don't know why the assignment directly or in constructor doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

IonViewDidEnter is Ionic’s lifecycle hook which fires quite “late in the game” after animation for your Homepage has finished and after classic init hooks like ngOnInit.

You must be calling for appPages value before it gets assigned. Try running property assignment inside ngOnInit() hook or inside Homepage constructor:

```
constructor() {
    this.appPages = AppPages.pages;
}
```

Comment: Still not working, i tried putting it in constructor but it's the same error, and the home.page.ts doesn't have ngOnInit so, i wrote that function and i put the assignement inside but doesn't works...

Comment: Also i edited the question and added another function, that function and the setup function are the unique functions where i use the variable appPages, works in setup, but doesn't works on hideShowMenu.

Comment: so what calls hideShowMenu? is that a button?

Comment: i think i know what’s going on, i think it’s Dependency Injection that needs to be here island hence my answer won’t be correct. i will update it in an hour

Comment: hideShowMenu display and hides some specific info in a menu depending on a tag of the JSON info, and later the menu will simple displayed

Comment: the code it's a bit large, but yeah i'm going to edit the question and put full code.

Comment: Hey man, sorry I do not think I can help any further as your code shared is not consistent and does not allow to build a full picture;/ the error you receive actually suggests that you might have 'this' scope issue, but its hard to say without full code available.